# Design a simple circuit to generate -21V..-24V from +5V

Tags: power-supply, lcd, inverter

I have got an old-STN-LCD which needs a very negative voltage, -21V..-24V are required in order to do the proper contrast, a current of less than 200nA is required, the LCD controller also requires a little ripple in the negative voltage supply.

How do you suggest me to design such a circuit?

Regards =)

Comment: What does "requires a little ripple" mean exactly? Can you quantify that?

Answer (score 2):

The [MAX686](http://datasheets.maxim-ic.com/en/ds/MAX686.pdf) runs from 5V and can generate adjustable bias voltages from -27.5V to +27.5V.  The datasheet linked above has example circuits.

Comment: Unfortunately Maxim once again confirms its reputation of being expensive: 8.37 in 1s at Digikey...